# Why isn't the static class ServicePointManager defined as static in the metadata?

Tags: c#, class, static, definition

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=netframework-4.8) we know the ServicePointManager is static. Yet if you go to its definition in Visual Studio (the metadata) it just shows `public class`, no `static` keyword. Why is that?

`Console`, for example, is defined as `public static class`.

Comment: The `static` keyword, applied to a class, just means that that it cannot be instantiated, and forces all members to also be declared static. If you look at [ServicePointManager](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/ServicePointManager.cs,86ab68f9e9462330), it has a private constructor and only has static members. So it looks like it could be made `static`, but doing so would make no difference in practice. Static classes were only introduced in C# 2, so it might well be that `ServicePointManager` was written back in C# 1. It uses the old `HashTable`, which supports this

Comment: @canton7, is the private constructor the reason you get an error when trying to instantiate the ServicePointManager, but not the "static classes cannot be instantiated error" but the "ServicePointManager does not contain a constructor that takes X parameters" where I have tested X to be from 1 to 6.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense